# Ionic 2 has exception when building android - cannot resolve gradle

Tags: gradle, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am a greenhorn to Ionic (ionic 2.2.3 and Cordova 7.0.1) and run into an exception when trying to build on android as below,

[image: Gradle error]

Since my site is behind proxy server, I added a gradle.properties to the folder (C:\Users\.gradle) like below, but get the exactly same error.

[image: proxy]

I was just wondering how to solve the network issue of gradle or use local gradle.

Answer (score 0):

This might help. Seems like quite a similar issue.
https://software.intel.com/es-es/forums/intel-xdk/topic/595059

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), make sure you read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and update your answer with more information.

Comment: it seems not work for me. I can build the app successfully at home without Proxy server, so it should be cause by Proxy.